# Ошибка при выборе категории для поста в форме

Tags: django, forms

У меня есть форма PostCreate и в ней есть поле category(выбор категории для поста):'`category':forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control'})` Когда я создаю пост через форму,то при выбор категории выскакивает вот такая вот ошибка:Выберите корректный вариант. Вашего варианта нет среди допустимых значений.Что с этим делать?
P.S Ошибка выскакивает именно из-за SelectMultiple потому что если я не буду описывать это поле в форме,то все будет работать

**UPDATE**
форма:

```
> class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     class Meta:
>         model = News
>         fields = ['title','text','category']
> 
>         widgets = {
>             'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Заголовок'}),
>             'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Текст'}),
>             'category':forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
>         }
```

Trecebak:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
        databases=databases,
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "D:\Python\Django\news\news\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
        path('news/',include('blog.urls'))
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "D:\Python\Django\news\news\apps\blog\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .views import *
      File "D:\Python\Django\news\news\apps\blog\views.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .forms import *
      File "D:\Python\Django\news\news\apps\blog\forms.py", line 4, in <module>
        class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 258, in __new__
        apply_limit_choices_to=False,
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 175, in fields_for_model
        formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 994, in formfield
        'blank': self.blank,
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 419, in formfield
        return super().formfield(**defaults)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 929, in formfield
        return form_class(**defaults)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1202, in __init__
        self.queryset = queryset
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1228, in _set_queryset
        self.widget.choices = self.choices
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 797, in _set_choices
        value = list(value)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1157, in __iter__
        yield self.choice(obj)
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1170, in choice
        ModelChoiceIteratorValue(self.field.prepare_value(obj), obj),
      File "C:\Users\Миша\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1261, in prepare_value
        if self.to_field_name:
    AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте просто

```
categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

Только это не в виджетах должно быть, а просто в форме.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ['title','text','category']

        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Заголовок'}),
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Текст'}),
        }
```

Comment: Пишет,что атрибута нет... AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'

Comment: Покажите всю форму и весь трейсбек.

Comment: обновил вопрос,там форма и трйсбек.

Comment: вы знаете как решить эту проблему?

Comment: @Miha_Taras обновил ответ.

Comment: Не сработало, выдаёт туже ошибку которая и была:AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name'

Comment: не может такого быть.

Comment: Ну получается может,я вставил точно такой-же код как у вас и такая-же ошибка.

Comment: залейте код на гитхаб - посмотрю.

Comment: Код чего именно(уточните файлы)?

Comment: модели, форма, контроллер, темплейт

Comment: понял,сейчас закину и сообщу вам,спасибо за помощь кстати!

Comment: https://github.com/MihaTarasov/django

Comment: @Miha_Taras залейте только тот контроллер, форму темплейт, урл, модели, которые связанны с этой проблемой. Или хотя бы рабочий код залейте на гит (с сеттингсами, реквайрементсами), чтобы я мог его у себя запустить.

Comment: Давайте я лучше скину только то, что нужно , т.к не зареган на гит

Comment: https://github.com/MihaTarasov/Django                              Скинул,то,что связано с проблемой